Shifting / moving entire layer in QGIS
I'm trying to work on two sets of data :

Public roads (official source, purple on the image)
Network data (private source, brown on the image)

Both layers should overlap (at least, the network data should be overlapping the roads) but they don't.
One of the layers is in EPSG:4326 - WGS 84, while the other is in Lambert_Conformal_Conic - projected. I tried to save the second one as WGS84 but it makes no difference.
I don't need the results to be super accurate, I'd just like both layers to "match" more or less where they are supposed to
I'd therefore like to find a way to move/shift the entire brown layer so that they match key points
Any idea on how to achieve this in QGIS 3?


Try Snap geometries to layer

You could look at the snap geometries tool as BERA suggested, trying different tolerances.  From your image it doesn't look like the problem is just a simple offset or scaling.  You could also try to georeference your vector data in the georeferencer (if it isn't a too old version); and try different transformations.

The entire principle of physically moving the location of shapes on a map is very intricate in even the most advanced proprietary GIS Software. There are also some questions you need to ask yourself before considering this.
1 - What are the Coordinate Systems / Projections of these feature classes? Could it be a simple reprojection that will solve this issue?
2 - What is your desired Coordinate System? If you use a cylindrical projection, your data will be flat and wide. If you use a Projected Coordinate System such as UTM, you data will be slightly curved depending on size.
If you do not care about spatial accuracy (you really should), see this answered post to achieve moving features in QGIS.
Move features to different geographic area

thanks for your reply ! I updated my question according to your details request

Have you tried setting your Project CRS to Projected and not Geographic, if it is at all? https://imgur.com/wT0cGlR
